# How do I prevent one TextView from pushing the other out of the screen?

Tags: android

**[SOLVED]** Marked the working solution. @GIBIN THOMAS: this suggestion works as well (similar).

Below I've posted an issue which arise when the Scoring increases, making it to expand and therefor push the other TextView out of the screen. I've tried changing the Width and height in all kinds of ways for both the TextViews themselves and the Layout that's wrapping them, without any luck.

**PROBLEM:** Anyone got a good solution how to set my Layout and/or TextViews width and height to prevent the Scoring TextView from pushing the Lives TextView out of the screen?

[image]
.

**This is my XML-file:**

The layout & textviews below are all inside another layout (including 4 buttons, one imageview and another textView - excluded in the code)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="@string/current_score"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/current_score_0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="205dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lives"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lives"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentLivesEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lives_5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Simply replace your current score linear layout with this relative layout and set `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`to currentScoreText and `android:layout_alignParenRight="true"` to currentScoreEasy. Please check complete block for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this layout:

use `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight` properly

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SCORE"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lives"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lives"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentLivesEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lives"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your issue

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Current Score"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Scrore"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lives"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Lives"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentLivesEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lives 5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please remove the strings i have added also if you have further doubts feel free to note down below

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, marked the working solution. But I tried yours as well and it works just as good! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to apply proper weight and other changes as follows :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="current_score"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="current_score_0"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lives"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="lives"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentLivesEasy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="lives_5"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the LinearLayout , layout_weight="5" .. Like

android:layout_weight="3"  and make the android:layout_width = "0px"

Note="Set the layout weight according to your spacing" ...

The Linear Layout in which u have fitted these two textviews

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply replace your current score linear layout with this relative layout and you are done.
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentScoreText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="current_score"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentScoreEasy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="current_score_0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've marked the working solution. But wanted to try this out as well and unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FisnikB. You found solution that's great. I'm using this and its working fine for me. I have made some edits as per your need. Can you please try it? Thanks

Comment: I assume the problem arise from the fact that you don't know how the rest of my coding looks like. Guess that's what throws you off. You just made a new edit right now?